# Using JVMTI to change Java bytecode at a runtime with C++

Tags: jvmti

I would like to know if anyone has had any luck modifying a Java methods bytecode at a run-time with JVMTI. JVMTI has a getter for a methods bytecode, but from what I understand it does not have any support for replacing the buffer. Any information would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a [class file load hook](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#ClassFileLoadHook) and retransform the classes you want to change.